# An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the ListObjects operation

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, policy

I might be missing something and could use a 2nd pair of eyes on these policies.

My bucket policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::redacted:role/myrole"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I checked the object permissions and for the only object in there I allow read and write access by everyone just to get this function to work (but it still does not).

Here is the lambda role I am using to access the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<my-bucket>/*",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:dynamo:table/myTable"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "polly:SynthesizeSpeech",
                "polly:StartSpeechSynthesisTask",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "polly:GetSpeechSynthesisTask"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Could it be that the function I am writing in lambda is wrong? Here is the part it breaks at:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME')
key = postId + "_" + title + ".mp3"
objs = list(bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key))
if len(objs) > 0 and objs[0].key == key:
   print("Exists!")
   boto3.client('s3').delete_object(Bucket='BUCKET_NAME', Key=key)
else:
  print("Doesn't exist")
```

I tried adding in ListObject as a policy action but I think it is just related to List bucket. I pulled the list bucket objects function from another answer because I am new at Python, but still seems like it should work at this point.

EDIT: Here is the exact error I receive in cloudwatch

```
An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the ListObjects 
  operation: All access to this object has been disabled: ClientError
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 33, in lambda_handler
```

EDIT 2: BUCKET_NAME is an environmental variable.

Comment: The key information missing in the question is, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: The title mentions "AllAccessDisabled". Is that the error?

Comment: Yes, in cloudwatch logs, the title of this question is the error, "An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the ListObjects operation" @Kannaiyan

Comment: Yes, I have other actions, like creating a new file, that do work with my policy. When I added the list() function this error appeared, but I thought my policy was already taking care of it. @NisseEngström

Comment: Do you have a region set in the code. If the region is missing, it will cause the same errors.

Comment: hm. I am in us-east-1. I thought if it is not specified, that would be the default. If there is not a default, could you remind me how to reference that for testing sake?  @Kannaiyan

Comment: According to the AWS Forums, It's possible that you might have an account specific issue: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=215212#215212

Comment: "All Access Disabled" means you are accessing a bucket that has been completely shut down by AWS. Potentially relevant: there is a bucket that exists in S3 that is actually named `BUCKET_NAME` and that bucket returns this error... and if your line `bucket = s3.Bucket('BUCKET_NAME')` is what's actually in your code, then you're accessing that bucket, rather than the one you are intending to access.

Comment: Thats interesting. I'm using key value pair for BUCKET_NAME, the value being the name of my bucket in the environmental variables section. I also reference the bucket like this without issue. unless writing it like ('BUCKET_NAME') is wrong. @Michael-sqlbot
      Bucket=os.environ['BUCKET_NAME'].

Comment: @JamieStarke I see. I may try their support line to get info about the bucket. I can try to comment the code that doesnt work out and see if I can still access my s3 bucket before I try that.

Comment: @PhilipMorgan If you're using environment variables, like you mentioned in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682632/an-error-occurred-allaccessdisabled-when-calling-the-listobjects-operation?noredirect=1#comment92307250_52682632), that would be good to include in the code.

Comment: You're right, I added for clarification. Apologies. @JamieStarke

Comment: I took out the afflicting code, and it works again. I believe I have the ability to create objects on my bucket, but I cannot list them for some reason.@JamieStarke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was assigning environmental variables incorrectly. The correct syntax is

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', 'us-east-1')
    bucket_name = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME'] <<<< this variable
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name) <<<<< into here
```

to assign environmental variables to your lambda code.

Answer (score 0):

about your aws role, this give you acess ? I had this problem, and was about my role.

Comment: The policies should be fine since everything else works besides the list function. I am currently going back and forth with AWS support and I will post an answer when they solve it.